# health check fails with 404 error after migrating to spring boot 2.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot

i'm new to spring boot and have just completed the migration of spring boot from 1.5 to 2.x for my app.
Everything seems to be fine except for the /health check which fails on "localhost" consistently. I looked for references over the internet but couldn't find any. Have somebody come across this? What could be the issue ?

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-08-29T07:06:02.3330000+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/health"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actuator endpoints are located under `/actuator` by default in Spring Boot 2 (try `/actuator/health`).

If you migrate to a major release, reading [the release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes) is quite important (in particular [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Release-Notes#actuator-improvements)). There is also a [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) if you have trouble upgrading.